# Mp4 Wrong length after capturing audio and video together using MediaSession

Tags: c++, video, media, ms-media-foundation

I'm developing an application to record .MP4 file with video and audio using Media session together. 
Below is my topology:

Video Source->Color transform->TeeNode ->H264 Encoder MFT->MPEG4 Sink

Audio source->AAC Encoder->MPEG4 Sink

I'm aggregating video and audio source and building the topology. Duration and length of the file are correct when I capture video alone, but duration and length of the file are wrong when I'm capturing video and audio together.

Please help me, how to solve this issue? Is possible to set sample time for every sample while recording the file using topology?

More input on this issue.

I have taken video with audio in Windows8 Store Camera app and checked the file length and bit rate and its working fine.I think this app used CaptureEngine technique for streaming and capturing but my application should support from Windows 7 onwards.

I checked the properties of video which is taken from my app and windows store app and attached screenshot here.

[image]

**Left side** image is taken from **WindowsStore App** and **right side** image is from **my app**.

Why video and audio bit rates are 0kbps. Can anyone tell me why the video is saving like this?

```
HRESULT AddVideoCompressionNode (IMFTopology* pTopology, IMFTopologyNode** ppVideoCompressionNode)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    IMFTopologyNode* pVideoCompNode = 0;
    UINT32 video_bit_rate;

    // Create transform
    m_pH264Transform = EnumerateEncoderMFT(TRUE,MFVideoFormat_H264,L"H264 Encoder MFT");

    UnlockHardwareMFT(m_pH264Transform);

    hr = MFCreateMediaType(&m_pVideoOutputMediaType);    if (FAILED(hr))    {   goto done;  }

    hr = m_pVideoOutputMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);    if (FAILED(hr))  {   goto done;  } 

    hr = m_pVideoOutputMediaType->SetUINT64(MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, m_uFrameSize);    if (FAILED(hr)) {   goto done;  }

    hr = m_pVideoOutputMediaType->SetUINT64(MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, m_uFrameRate);    if (FAILED(hr)) {   goto done;  }

    hr = m_pVideoOutputMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, MFVideoInterlace_Progressive);    if (FAILED(hr)) {   goto done;  }

    hr = m_pVideoOutputMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_H264);    if (FAILED(hr))    {   goto done;  }

    hr = GetEncodingBitrate(m_pColorConvMediaType,&video_bit_rate);    if (FAILED(hr))  {   goto done;  }

    hr = m_pVideoOutputMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE, video_bit_rate);    if (FAILED(hr))  {   goto done;  }

    hr = m_pVideoOutputMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_MPEG2_PROFILE, eAVEncH264VProfile_Main);    if (FAILED(hr))   {   goto done;  }

    hr = m_pH264Transform->SetOutputType(0, m_pVideoOutputMediaType, 0);    if (FAILED(hr)) {   goto done;  }

    hr = m_pH264Transform->SetInputType(0, m_pColorConvMediaType, 0);    if (FAILED(hr))    {   goto done;  }

    SafeRelease(&m_pColorConvMediaType);

    hr = MFCreateTopologyNode(MF_TOPOLOGY_TRANSFORM_NODE, &pVideoCompNode);    if (FAILED(hr))  {   goto done;  }

    hr = pVideoCompNode->SetObject((IUnknown*) m_pH264Transform);    if (FAILED(hr))    {   goto done;  }

    hr = pTopology->AddNode(pVideoCompNode);    if (FAILED(hr)) {   goto done;  }

    *ppVideoCompressionNode = pVideoCompNode;

done:
    SafeRelease(&pVideoCompNode);
    return hr;
}

HRESULT AddAudioCompressionNode (IMFTopology* pTopology, IMFTopologyNode** pAudioCompressionNodep)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    IMFTopologyNode* pAudioCompNode = 0;

    m_pAACTransform = EnumerateEncoderMFT(FALSE,MFAudioFormat_AAC,L"");    if (FAILED(hr))  {   goto done;  }

    hr = MFCreateMediaType(&m_pAACMediaType);    if (FAILED(hr))    {   goto done;  }

    hr = m_pAACMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Audio);     if (FAILED(hr)) {   goto done;  }

    hr = m_pAACMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFAudioFormat_AAC);    if (FAILED(hr)) {   goto done;  }

    hr = m_pAACMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS, 2);    if (FAILED(hr))    {   goto done;  }

    hr = m_pAACMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND, 44100);    if (FAILED(hr))  {   goto done;  }

    hr = m_pAACMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE, 16);    if (FAILED(hr))    {   goto done;  }

    hr = m_pAACMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_AVG_BYTES_PER_SECOND, 12000);    if (FAILED(hr))    {   goto done;  }

    hr = m_pAACMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AAC_PAYLOAD_TYPE,0);    if (FAILED(hr))   {   goto done;  }

    hr = m_pAACMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AAC_AUDIO_PROFILE_LEVEL_INDICATION,0x29);    if (FAILED(hr))  {   goto done;  }

    hr = m_pAACMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_BLOCK_ALIGNMENT,1);    if (FAILED(hr))  {   goto done;  }

    hr = m_pAACMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT,0);    if (FAILED(hr))    {   goto done;  }

    hr = m_pAACMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE,96000);    if (FAILED(hr))    {   goto done;  }

    hr = m_pAACTransform->SetOutputType(0, m_pAACMediaType, 0);    if (FAILED(hr))  {   goto done;  }

    hr = m_pAACTransform->SetInputType(0, m_pSrcAudioMediaType, 0);    if (FAILED(hr))  {   goto done;  }

    SafeRelease(&m_pSrcAudioMediaType);

    hr = MFCreateTopologyNode(MF_TOPOLOGY_TRANSFORM_NODE, &pAudioCompNode);    if (FAILED(hr))  {   goto done;  }

    hr = pAudioCompNode->SetObject((IUnknown*) m_pAACTransform);    if (FAILED(hr)) {   goto done;  }

    hr = pTopology->AddNode(pAudioCompNode);    if (FAILED(hr)) {   goto done;  }

    *pAudioCompressionNodep = pAudioCompNode;

done:
    SafeRelease(&pAudioCompNode);
    return hr;
}
```

Then, I tried to save audio alone hence I removed video media type in sink and captured the audio. Then i checked the length of the file and its giving wrong length.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can implement an IMFTransform derived MFT that will modify the samples' timestamps, but I'm not sure that Media Session will like it. As an alternative approach in order to have control on the samples you can use Source Reader to Sink Writer approach for this scenario. I used it in different capture/re-encode projects and it works much better than Media Session.

Comment: I have implemented IMFTransform derived MFT and connected in topology but no luck and still issue persist. Already I have been worked with source reader to record video and audio but I couldn't combine both audio and video using this technique. Can you please share sample application to record video and audio together using source reader?

Comment: Any help @Vuvrit?

Comment: Basically you need to follow the instructions from here and add the IMFSinkWriter and WriteSample calls in the OnReadSample: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg583871(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Vuvrit. Already I have used source reader technique and faced some issue to combine audio and video together. I have posted a query in the following link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43238552/noise-occurs-while-encoding-audio-from-microphone-and-latency-in-video-streaming/43248900?noredirect=1#comment73758426_43248900...please have a look on it

Comment: I don't have access to the source code of your other post. You have to properly timestamp both video and audio samples and Write them to the writer in sync. Maybe you need to debug the timestamps of the samples you send to the writer.

Comment: Any help @Vuvirt?

Comment: do you still need help with this?

Comment: Sorry for the delay.Yes VuVirt, I need your help to solve this issue. Kindly help me out with this?

Comment: please send me full source code to my email (from the profile) so I can test it and come up with a solution for you

Comment: Sorry for the delay vuvirt...I'm on vacation now so I will send my code in the month of Jan2018.

Comment: no worries, have a nice vacation and holidays